# reset toggle in the navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to bring my menu button back to its original state once you click the body or close button.

What I mean is when you click the menu button you will see that it switches to an x. Once you click the x it will switch back to the menu icon. I would like to mimic this same event once you click outside the button or the close button.

```
$(".gn-icon-menu").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4fjf/18/

Comment: are you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/f4fjf/22/

Comment: yes I was thank you @Pravin Vaichal

Comment: posted answer with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click event on the `document` like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($(".gn-icon-menu").hasClass('on')) {
        $(".gn-icon-menu").removeClass('on');
    }
});
```

You have to `stopPropagation` on your `.gn-icon-menu` click event:

```
$(".gn-icon-menu").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4fjf/21/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('body').click(function(evt){
    if(evt.target.class == ".gn-icon-menu")
       return;
    $(".gn-icon-menu").removeClass('on')
 });

 $(".gn-icon-menu").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4fjf/24/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f4fjf/22/)**

**Javascript**

```
$("body").not(".gn-icon-menu").click(function() {
   $(".gn-icon-menu").removeClass("on");
});

$(".gn-icon-menu").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

Hope it helps